# How to create a column with fields from two columns based on different column

Tags: sql-server

I am having a request where I need to combine the values of two columns into one column based on a criteria. Is this possible in SQL?

If the customer name starts with 'ims-' then the createddate value needs to be added to the combineddate column, if the customer name starts with 'ims-i-' then the recieveddate needs to be added to the combineddate column

My table is like below:

```
customer      createddate   reciveddate   combineddate
ims-123      10-02-2015                    10-02-2015
1ms-i-562                    15-03-2022    15-03-2022
ims-987      10-05-2021                    10-05-2021
ims-i-345                    16-09-2022    16-09-2022
```

I am not sure how to go about doing this, I tried using the CASE statement, but it doesnt work.

```
CASE  
            WHEN customer like 'ims-%' THEN createddate 
            WHEN customer like 'ims-i-%' THEN recieveddate 
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS combineddate
```

Comment: `CASE Flag` - so what is `Flag`? What does *doesn't work* actually mean?

Comment: Switch the two `WHEN` statements around. Your first statement also would cover `ims-i-` customers.

Comment: Sorry that was the error I was getting. Is this the best way, to bring the data into one column

Comment: @eddeveloper - *what* was the error you were getting?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use an `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` as long as the missing dates are `NULL`. This example will only work if the production data doesn't deviate from the sample you posted. With the coalesce, we are prioritizing the `receiveddate` over the `createddate` which is what you are essentially trying to do.

```
SELECT c.*
    , COALESCE(c.receiveddate, c.createddate) as combineddate
FROM customer as c
```